# Expo ReactNative app, Push Notification works on Expo GO, doesn't work on App Store standalone app

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo, apple-push-notifications, mobile-application

in my react native expo app, push notification is working on Expo Go but it's not working on standalone app. I complete push notification certificate things on Apple Developer side, but still it doesn't work. Any suggest?

I created APN Key,
I created Apple Push Service Certificates both for App Store and for sandbox. I included these things into app. When I open the app from expo go, push notification token is generating. But when I open the app from standalone app, push notification token is not generating. I need your suggestions, help. Thank you very much.